# Оптимизация запроса where group by

Tags: mysql, запрос, оптимизация, group-by, order

Имею запрос

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(dl.`date_col`, '%Y-%m-%d') AS dateF 
FROM table_name dl 
WHERE dl.`date_col` BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2017-12-01' 
GROUP BY date(dateF) 
ORDER BY dateF;
```

Время работы 0.735. Как его можно оптимизировать? Пробовал подобный запрос

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(dl.`date_col`, '%Y-%m-%d') as dateF 
FROM table_name dl 
GROUP BY date(dateF) 
HAVING dl.`date_col` BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2017-12-01'
ORDER BY dateF;
```

Время получилось 0.657, но все таки не хорошо пихать в having, то что должно быть в where. explain-ы для запросов соответственно:

```
'1', 'SIMPLE', 'dl', 'index', NULL, 'uid', '9', NULL, '767882', 
'Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort' (where)

'1', 'SIMPLE', 'dl', 'index', NULL, 'uid', '9', NULL, '767883', 
'Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort'  (having)
```

База MyISAM. Структура таблицы:

```
'CREATE TABLE `table_name` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`date_col` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT \'0000-00-00 00:00:00\',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`))
```

Comment: А вам точно не будут нужны никакие колонки кроме даты ? И какой индекс сейчас используется ?

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT(date_col, '%Y-%m-%d') dateF FROM table_name WHERE date_col BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2017-12-01' ORDER BY 1`

Comment: @Mike, count(*) еще вывожу для каждой группы, собственно все. Сделал индекс и на id, и на date_col.

Comment: Что же вы этого в вопросе то не указали, видите @Akina уже вариант с distinct придумал, который разумеется не будет работать если нужен count(). Что то мне подсказывает что быстрее просто некуда. Разве что хранить готовые count() (сохраненные триггерами или ежедневной процедурой)

Comment: @Akina, время работы запроса 0,843.
В данном случае destinct отрабатывает хуже group by

Comment: @Mike, там не настолько принципиально, что вывожу кроме даты. Просто интересно уменьшение скорости работы.

Comment: Единственная оптимизация - это использовать индекс по `date_col` для отбора. Но он и так используется. А дальше группировка по выражению, и возможности для оптимизации кончились. Ну разве что после группировки по выражению не нужно сортировать по тому же выражению - выходной набор и так будет по нему отсортирован.

Comment: @KordDEM Да вот нет, как раз очень принципиально. если бы кроме count например были бы нужны хотя бы еще какие нибудь колонки то запрос бы дольше работал и подход в возможной оптимизации был бы в корне другой. И я надеюсь вы понимаете, что у вас эти два запроса возвращают разные данные (первый неправильно даст количество по 1 декабря) А второй быстрее только пока в таблице в основном 2017 год, а если будет лет 5, то уже может оказаться медленнее

Comment: Теоретически можно пойти на предрасчётное переопределение и добавить в таблицу индексированное поле даты, заполняемое/обновляемое триггерной логикой, если исключить иные способы его изменения (только читать). Тогда его использование в этом запросе даст серьёзный профит. Но от триггера пострадает быстродействие других запросов, и надо будет убедиться, что нет с полем даты-времени каскадных и прочих, не вызывающих срабатывания триггеров, операций. Плюс, конечно, на всякий случай создать пересчётную процедуру для этого поля. Вот только стОит ли задача такого геморроя?

Comment: @Mike, объясните почему "первый неправильно даст количество по 1 декабря"(с)?

Comment: потому что он от 01.12.2017 возьмет только записи с временем 00:00 дата должна быть `2017-12-01 23:59:59` или не использовать between и верхнюю дату проверять на `date_col < '2017-12-02'`

Comment: @Akina, для развития интересно узнать и попробовать)

Comment: @Mike, действительно, что-то я упустил это из виду)

Comment: Ну так узнайте: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/triggers.html , да попробуйте. Делов-то...

Comment: хотя второй то же даст такую же ошибку, потому что возьмет в having первое попавшееся значение даты из группы и оно может быть не 00:00. по хорошему в group by вы вообще не имеете права использовать не сгруппированную колонку

Comment: Кстати... а зачем Вам ДВА индекса по полю ID?

Comment: @Akina, это просто косяк проектирования)

Answer (score 0):

Возможное решение по "оптимизации" запроса путём переопределения данных:

```
-- добавить поле с датой
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD COLUMN only_date_col DATE;
-- пересчитать его значения
UPDATE table_name SET only_date_col = DATE(date_col);
-- проиндексировать поле
CREATE INDEX idx_only_date ON table_name (only_date_col);
-- создать триггеры, обновляющие поле при вставке/изменении данных
CREATE TRIGGER bi_table_name ON table_name BEFORE INSERT 
    FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.only_date_col = DATE(NEW.date_col);
CREATE TRIGGER bu_table_name ON table_name BEFORE UPDATE 
    FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.only_date_col = DATE(NEW.date_col);
```

Соответственно запрос трансформируется в

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(only_date_col, '%Y-%m-%d') AS dateF, COUNT(*) AS cnt 
FROM table_name
WHERE only_date_col BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2017-12-01' 
GROUP BY only_date_col;
```

При возникновении подозрений на несогласованность данных (или в процедуре обслуживания БД) - запускать запрос пересчёта значений `UPDATE` для согласования данных в поле `only_date_col`.

**ВАЖНО!** Следует понимать, что данное изменение ухудшит производительность большинства других запросов (если они, как и оптимизируемый запрос, не используют часть даты из поля даты-времени - тогда переписывание их на использование добавленного поля может улучшить их выполнение), а также увеличит расход дискового пространства.

Comment: Если mysql 5.7 или новее - то вместо триггеров стандартный generated column `ALTER TABLE table_name ADD COLUMN only_date_col DATE as (date(date_col)) virtual;`